# How do I get two independent Laravel apps to run concurrently on the same development machine?

Tags: laravel

I am developing apps in Laravel 9.45 on a Windows 10 machine. While I am focusing on developing my newest app, I sometimes want to be able to run one of my older apps on the same machine so that I can compare the behaviour of the two apps. However, when I try to start the second app, it gets assigned to the same localhost:8000 as the first app which is already running, which messes up BOTH apps. How can I get the second app to run independently in, say, localhost:8001?

```
UPDATE:
```

Sorry for omitting how I am starting the apps. I am using XAMPP for my development environment so my database is MySQL/MariaDB. The app I am currently developing gets started by running `npm run dev` in one terminal window (to start vite) and `php artisan serve` in the other. The second app that I want to run doesn't use vite so just needs me to run `php artisan serve`.

Comment: You need to provide details on how you are starting the server(s). I'm sure you can pass a port parameter when starting

Comment: As levi mentioned, you need to tell us how you are running both apps, it is imposible for us to help if you don't share how you are running stuff... the simple solution is to have docker or using nginx/apache have 2 sites, but again, without what you have it is imposible for us to help... it should be very basic...

Comment: `php artisan serve --port=8081` will run on localhost:8081. more options `php artisan serve --help`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the solution is very simple. When starting the second app, just pass a port number that differs from the one used by the first app. Since my first app was using the default port of 8000, I started my second app with:

```
php artisan serve --port=8001
```

I had hoped it would be that easy but I'd forgotten that I could find out about options for artisan commands by prefixing the command, serve in this case, with the word help. For example, `php artisan help serve`. Executing that revealed that I could append `--port=nnnn` to specify a port on which the app was supposed to run.